# Why do we use rejection sampling even we know the distribution?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, sampling, descriptive-statistics

I already read this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90215/rejection-sampling) and I have the exact same questions. Below I pulled the first question and the answer from the post.

> Therefore we still use the distribution of p for the randomly generated values x.

Computing the density, $p$, isn't the same as sampling random variables from the distribution $p$ is the density *for*.

**My question is:** why computing the density, p, isn't the same as sampling random variables from the distribution p is the density for? In my sense, if I know the pdf and all parameters of a distribution, I can randomly generate a set of x value and I can compute the probability density for each x, **then we generate a random variable with a set of x values and probability density**, so why do I still need rejection sampling or any other sampling methods to generate a bunch of x and its density? Maybe I misunderstand the meaning of generating random variables?

Comment: Could you explain or illustrate what you do understand by "generating random variables"?

Comment: @Scortchi Edited it

Comment: Still a bit puzzling. When you say "I can randomly generate a set of x values" that's according to what distribution? How would you sample from an exponential distribution with rate parameter 2, say? (Density function $f(x)=2\exp(-2x)$.)

Comment: @Scortchi If I have a continuous uniform distribution at [0,2], then its pdf is 0.5. My x values can be manually generated as 0.0001, 0.0002, ..., 1.9999, each value corresponds to probability density 0.5, my random variable X, whose P(X = xi) = 0.5. This is the way how I generate an RV.

Comment: So you're not randomly generating anything; you're writing down a sequence & evaluating the density function of each element. Random number generation is the simulation of outcomes according to a stochastic model. It's throwing a die & getting a sequence like $2, 3, 1, 5, 3, \ldots$.

Comment: @Scortchi Strictly speaking, it is not a random generation. But what is the point here to do rejection sampling? If I know the distribution, I can plug any number to pdf then get the probability density, why do I need sampling from the distribution using complex methods.

Comment: Even loosely speaking, that's not random number generation. It seems as if your question should have been "why would you ever want to generate a random number?" - there doesn't seem to be any issue specific to rejection sampling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you have the formula for a density, say $p(x)$, in order to generate samples from it, you'll have to devise a method. Many known densities (like exponential, normal, gamma etc.) have library methods to sample from, though they use specific methods to generate those samples. [Inverse Transform Sampling](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Inverse_transform_sampling) is one of the basic of those, which uses uniform RVs. [Box-Muller Transform](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) is another, a little bit more complicated (compared to ITS above) method to sample normal RVs. So, how you generate your samples from uniform RVs or any other way is actually another problem; and having the exact $p(x)$ is not that constructive in this way.